# JIRA - вывести с помощью фильтра задачи с открытыми подзадачами

Tags: jira

никак не могу с помощью стандартного функционала вывести задачи с открытыми подзадачи. Вывести нужно только задачи, без отображения подзадач.

Comment: Добрый день, вы нашли решение?